# Django: change inlines based on select option

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-views

Category has "types" (for example, three types of categories). Each category may have any number of Videos. And each Video, published in Category of '1' type may have any number of Pictures. But for Video, published in '2' and '3' Category types there are no Pictures.

**models.py**:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    CHOICES =  (
                 ('1','1'),
                 ('2','2'),
                 ('3','3'),
               )
    type = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES)

class Video(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class Picture(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video)
    title = models.Charfield()
```

**admin.py**:

```
class PictureInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Picture
    extra = 5

class VideoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PictureInline,]
```

**question**:

When i add Video item, and selecting Category for it, how can i dinamically show PictureInline based on what type of Category i selected for Video?

If i select first Category in select list, i want to be ablle to see PictureInline in admin, and if i select other Categories, i didn't want to see PictureInline.

Is it possible?

**PS**: I found https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects but didn't find such functionality for inlines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use JavaScript to dynamically hide/show the inline set. The id of the inline set is always `#[related_name]-group`.

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){

        function togglePictureInline(selected) {
            $.getJSON('/ajax/category-type/', { id: selected }, function (data, jqXHR) {
                if (data[0].fields.type == 1)
                    $('#pictures-group').show();
                else
                    $('#pictures-group').hide();
            });
        }

        var $category = $('#id_category');
        togglePictureInline($category.val());
        $category.change(function(){
            togglePictureInline($(this).val());
        });
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

**yourapp/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404
from django.core import serializers

def ajax_category_type(request):
    id = request.GET.get('id')
    categories = get_list_or_404(Category, id=id)
    data = serializers.serialize('json', categories, fields=('type',))
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

Add the following to `VideoAdmin`:

```
class VideoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    class Media:
        js = ('path/to/this.js',)
```

Or override `templates/yourapp/video/change_form.html` with:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
{% block extrahead %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script src="path/to/this.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've changed the JavaScript above to include an AJAX request. You're going to have to use AJAX because you've got to fetch the selected Category before you can get the type of it. I've also added a basic view you can use to return the data you need. You just need to hook the view up in your urls.py and change the URL in the AJAX call to match.

Comment: Thanks! Now i can dynamically show / hide Inlines according to selected Category. But in question i wrote, that appearence or disappearance of inlines depends on Category.type. Any variants to upgrade that great solution? I suppose, we need some query inside JS function to determine what type of category is selected.

Comment: Answer above has been updated to include the necessary AJAX functionality.