# URL for JQuery.getJSON()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506439/django-change-inlines-based-on-select-option) to get variable inlines for my Django admin page. Everything is functioning until this line in the javascript function:

```
$.getJSON('/ajax/category-type/', .....)
```

where the server comes up with a 404 for `/ajax/category-type/`. I'm not very familiar with AJAX (or JSONs) so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Is this a placeholder URL that I need to fill in? Am I missing a dependency? (I tried installing django-ajax to my project but that didn't change anything.)

I feel like this is probably something stupid simple that I'm missing.

**Edit:**

I did need to add this url to my urls.py, but that only partially fixed the problem.

After fixing that problem, I added a print statement to the view, which confirms that it's being hit when I go to the admin page. But immediately following that, I'm still getting the same 404 error in the server. It's always getting a 404 from the line `categories = get_list_or_404(Category, id=id)`. I believe this should be getting all the `Category`s with the `id`, but I'm not sure what the id actually is in this case.

Comment: Surely that's just a url that you need to set on your urls.py to point at the view in that answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax URL needs to point to a valid resource on your backend (django). I'm not terribly familiar with django, but if it's a REST framework you can probably define resources on your backend by defining routes, e.g. 'api/users/{id}', which might return users by their ID. But it needs to be something you've defined beforehand. Looks like there's some documentation on this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

One way you can tell if it's a valid URL to ajax (getJSON) to is to put it in your browser and see if it comes back with anything. You'll need to include the domain as well when you put it in your browser of course, e.g. `http://localhost:64611/ajax/category-type/`

Comment: Yeah, I did need to add the URL to my urls.py. I also added a print statement to the view, which confirms that it's being hit when I go to the admin page. But immediately following that, I'm still getting the same 404 in the server. It's always getting a 404 from `categories = get_list_or_404(Category, id=id)`. I'm not even sure what the `id` is referring to in this...

Comment: I don't know what all your app is supposed to do or what your URLs look like, but I'd guess you need to include a valid Category ID in your URL, e.g. `/ajax/category-type/1`. I'm guessing this looks for that ID in some database and returns a 404 if it doesn't find it. But I'm really just guessing here - sounds like you need to read up on this example a little more and figure out how it's supposed to work. Either way, if your request is hitting the backend, then your original question is technically answered and your request is now using a "valid" URL. Just need a valid ID